# How to handle model / API response translation in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, rest

I have an angular application that requests data from a JSON API. A sample API response might be:

```
{
  id: 1,
  name: 'JJ',
  houseId: 2
}
```

In my angular application I will have models representing a User, which also has a reference to a House object:

```
{
  id: 1,
  firstName: 'JJ',
  surname: '',
  house: {
    id: 2,
    address: 'XXX'
  }
}
```

The application model and API responses differ in that there is one field for the name in the API response, but two in my application model. Is there an 'angular' way I can do some transformation from an API call response object to my application model to ensure that I am always dealing with consistent objects in my controllers/services?

Related to this, the API responds with the database id of the house object associated with that user, and not with the full house object included in the JSON. Is there a way to set my object up to automatically resolve this when needed?

As an example, I would like to display this user, with his address. If the object was fully resolved I could use 'user.house.address'. However, using the plain JSON response object, this would be undefined. Instead of having to explicitly resolve the house object by using the house API with the houseId, I would like this to happen 'behind the scenes' by previously stating how such an id would be resolved if the object is accessed.

Or am I approaching this the wrong way and the API response should be used to dictate the data structure of my application and explicit lookups via object id's is the preferred way?

Comment: How about creating additional service layer between rest endpoint and other controllers/services? The responsibility would be to perform all necessary rest calls to build complete User object and to perform necessary conversions.